# Multi-Tenant authentication with Spring Security in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, multi-tenant

I am trying to authenticate in a multi tenant Grails application. I have done the s2-quickstart and here is my User class(named as MyUser):

```
class MyUser {

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired
    Tenant tenant

    static hasMany = [classes:FitnessClassSchedule]
    static belongsTo = [Tenant,FitnessClassSchedule]

    static transients = ['springSecurityService']

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: 'tenant'
        password blank: false
        classes nullable:true
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }

    Set<SecRole> getAuthorities() {
        MyUserSecRole.findAllByMyUser(this).collect { it.secRole }
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : password
    }
}
```

The constraint on username that it should be unique within a tenant means that something ("username1","password1","tenant1") and ("username1","password1","tenant2") is possible. Hence by just merely username and password, we can not identify the authenticating user(which is why it seems that I am not able to login even after initializing a few users in bootstrap.groovy). So we need to pass a third parameter as the tenant under which to identify the user and I don't seem to figure out a way for doing this.

Since I am using spring-security-core:2.0-RC4 on grails 2.3.7, the login controller is not explicitly generated, so overriding seems difficult.

So how do I do it? Is it possible to do so without overriding the controller?

Comment: Overriding the controller is quite simple. Just create a controller by the same name. Here is the source for the controller if you want to look at it: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/springsecurity/LoginController.groovy as far as your actual issue, it's going to be more complex than just overriding the controller. You will need to read up on spring security to understand why.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @JoshuaMoore! Multi tenancy is a very fundamental issue as it would need to be sorted out whenever we are designing a SAAS application. So what is the recommended way to solve the authentication issue with it? I guess if something is very rife, a recommended solution to it should be there. Do you know something that can make my life easier in grails?

Comment: There are a vast number of plugins that attempt to solve this issue. I am very familiar with multi tenancy (all of my apps are in fact multi tennat). However, issues arise due to how multi tenancy can be different. There is no one solution for such a broad issue. Depending on your needs you may find this helpful: http://grails.org/plugin/multi-tenant-spring-security otherwise I recommend looking at other multi tenant plugins already available and see if they work for you, beyond that, implement your own solution/plugin (which is what I do because of my requirements).

Comment: @JoshuaMoore the plugin you suggested combines multi tenant core http://www.grails.org/plugin/multi-tenant-core and spring security. unfortunately the multi tenant core is not used these days. as its not compatiable with grails 2.x(see link of that plugin). I am not sure how to go about now. Also that multi-tenant-spring-security plugin was updated last in 2010, so its too obsolete. I think multi tenancy is a very common topic and i understand there are some approaches(single db, multiple db etc..), but grails should have something simple for such things. Quiet shocked to find its not!!

Comment: It's more complex than single db or multiple db. There is deployment strategy, tenant resolution, etc. That's mainly the reason why there isn't a single plugin to address these issues. The above plugins were intended to give you a hint of how you could address the issue yourself. I personally haven't ever used the plugins, though I did watch them mature to the point they were at. You may want to strongly consider creating your own plugin and publishing it for the community if your requirements aren't very unique (as mine are).

Comment: Typically if Grails doesn't address an issue it could be one of two things (in my humble opinion). 1. It's an opportunity for you to give back to the community, or 2. Your approach is wrong or too specific to be addressed with a community based plugin,.